# Event Handlers not Firing for Winform Launched from Excel Addin Ribbon

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel Addin Ribbon that adds buttons to the Excel context menu. The context menu instantiates a form class for performing certain actions. These actions work fine, except for one button, which actually shows the form. The form launches, but the event handlers on the form do not call the their respective methods. So the buttons and other elements on the form will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue was that in the form loading method, InitializeComponent() was called. Removing it from the load method resolved the issue for some reason.

Comment: The InitializeComponent() call should be in the constructor.  Why yours was in the load event is unclear since you never posted any code.